# Can't Find the result

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
  ID | ID_MESIN |PIC         | Due Date |
________________________________________
    1 | 1081     | Hariyanto |12/12/2013
    2 | 1081     | Budi      |13/12/2013
    3 | 1059     | Jono      |23/12/2013
    4 | 1059     | Yuki      |24/12/2013
```

I need a query that gives the last row per ID_MESIN Column.

ex : if I run the Query with ID_Mesin = 1059 then result is

```
4 | 1059     | Yuki      |24/12/2013`
```

if I run  the Query with ID_Mesin = 1081 the result is

```
2 | 1081     | Budi      |13/12/2013
```

I have query Like this:

```
 SELECT * , MAX( ID ) AS ID FROM mytable WHERE ID_MESIN = '1081'
```

and like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID_MESIN = '1081' AND  ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM mytable)
```

But the result is wrong:

```
 2 | 1081     | Hariyanto    |12/12/2013
```

ID and ID_MESIN is true but other column is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID_MESIN = '1081' 
AND ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM mytable where ID_MESIN = '1081')
```

If you wanted the highest ID rows for all ID_MESIN values:

```
select t.* 
from mytable t
join (select id_mesin, max(id) as id from mytable group by id_mesin) m
  on t.id_mesin = m.id_mesin and t.id = m.id
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just need only one rows. And I know my query is close. Only need where ID_MESIN = '1081' Thanks a lot. :)